# How to make a disconnected graph to be 1-edge-connected(but not 2-edge-connected) with some shortest edge

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Assume I have a graph.You can run following code to get it.

```
nearGraph =Import["http://halirutan.github.io/Mathematica-SE-Tools/decode.m"][
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWP6J.png"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is a disconnected graph.But I can connect it every component in this method.

```
SeedRandom[331]
pathGraph = 
 PathGraph[
  v = point[[Last@
      FindShortestTour[
       point = RandomChoice /@ ConnectedComponents[nearGraph]]]], 
  VertexCoordinates -> Most@v]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Union this graph with original graph.

```
resultGraph = GraphUnion[nearGraph, pathGraph];
HighlightGraph[
 Graph[resultGraph, 
  VertexCoordinates -> VertexList[resultGraph]], pathGraph]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{KEdgeConnectedGraphQ[resultGraph, 1],KEdgeConnectedGraphQ[resultGraph, 2]}
```

> {True, False}

Yep.It's a connected now.But I don't really content with it.In my expectation.I wanna get a graph (maybe) like:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It just cost a shortest edge can do this.I know the position or distance in `Graph` will not impact the result of calculation.In some case I have a demand like this maybe.I think we can see the distance as a edge weight to solve it.But I don't know how to implement it.

---

## Update

As the [@Rahul comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111460/how-to-make-a-disconnected-graph-to-be-1-edge-connectedbut-not-2-edge-connected/111466#comment302626_111460).I reemphasize the target that is the title of this topic :). We want to get a **1-edge-connected(but not 2-edge-connected)**.It can be the picture of the following

[image]

Comment: Is it necessary that the new edges form (conceptually) a cycle? Would it not be allowed for the bottom red edge to go from the bottom left component to the component above the bottom right one instead?

Comment: @Rahul Yes,it is allowed completely.Actually I don't know my sketch graph whether or not exact.It just need cost shortest edge and make it be 1-edge-connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just carry [Wjx's code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118148/21532) for this problem.Maybe more beauty solution can do this.

```
l = VertexList@neargraph;
coor = PropertyValue[{neargraph, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ l;
g = Graph[Range@Length@l, EdgeList@neargraph /. Thread[l -> Range@Length@l], 
   VertexCoordinates -> coor];

cc = ConnectedComponents@g;
pts = Map[{#, PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates]} &, cc, {2}];
pre = First@MinimalBy[#, Last] & /@ 
   Apply[{#1[[1]] <-> #2[[1]], Norm[#1[[2]] - #2[[2]]]} &, 
    Tuples /@ Subsets[pts, {2}], {2}];
spt = EdgeList@
   FindSpanningTree[
    CompleteGraph[Length@cc, EdgeWeight -> pre[[;; , 2]]]];
res = Extract[pre, 
   First@Position[
       UndirectedEdge @@@ Subsets[Range@Length@cc, {2}], #] & /@ spt];
res[[;; , 2]] // Total
HighlightGraph[g~EdgeAdd~res[[;; , 1]], res[[;; , 1]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

```
g = nearGraph;
cc = ConnectedComponents@g; 
orderComps = Last@FindShortestTour[#] &@(Mean /@ cc); 
nfs = Nearest /@ (cc[[#]] & /@ orderComps); 
mins = MapThread[ Function[{nf, points}, SortBy[{#, First@nf@#} & /@ points, 
                  EuclideanDistance @@ # &][[1]]][##] &,
                 {nfs,  RotateRight[cc[[orderComps]], 1]}];
ud = UndirectedEdge @@@ mins;
HighlightGraph[EdgeAdd[g, ud], ud]
```

Almost!

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: 1)I try to understand the code.it look very nice.But [a inexplicable edge](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lCykI.png) will be add(the left loop).2)I have some worry about the method use the `Mean /@ cc` to sort the connected component in some complicated case.But the `FindShortestTour` not support the `Interval`.3)I don't sure the result must be a cycle.like the [comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111460/how-to-make-a-disconnected-graph-to-be-1-edge-connectedbut-not-2-edge-connected?noredirect=1#comment302626_111460) mention

Comment: Dr. belisarius, you seem to be taking a break from Stack Exchange, but I want to congratulate you on breaking the 100k "reputation" barrier, for what that is worth to you. :-)